# How to setup nginx ingress controller , such that the kubernetes pod remains http but the nginx serves request on https

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, https, kubernetes-ingress

How can i setup nginx in such a way that in the nginx reverse proxy , we proxy pass set to http://xyz ( i.e redirecting to the kubernetes pod )
i want only my nginx to be made as https , i dont want to change the proxy pass to https , would it be possible

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, what you describe is the **default behavior** of an Ingress Controller:

the SSL/TLS Termination is done by the Ingress Controller and the downstream traffic to the nodes is over HTTP.

Comment: Thanks , would the default behavior apply from nginx to ingress also?

Comment: With nginx you mean your Nginx Ingress Controller?

Comment: No , i have a nginx which is configured with reverse proxy to the minikube environment kubernetes pod , , so if i only make the nginx as ssl and in the reverse proxy had something like   location ~ ^/test {
    proxy_pass http://test.host;
   }                      where the test.host is mapped to the minikube ip